# How do you set up a confirmation prompt before running a task in a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I want to install MariaDB after confirming user. I have a role and one simple task:

```
- name: install MariaDB
  yum:
    name: MariaDB
    state: present
```

or if I want to use `include: MySQL.yml`, if the user wants to, this line executes, if not skip this include.

```
- name: install MariaDB
  yum:
    name: MariaDB
    state: present

- include: MySQL.yml
```

**more explain**

my hosts:

```
[dbs]
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
```

Now, I want if the user enters no for answer prompt, MySQL.yml does not execute for any server.

my code in role (`tasks/main.yml`):

```
---
- pause:
   prompt: "Do you want to install mariadb (yes/no)?"
  register: my_pause
  delegate_to: localhost

- include_tasks: mysql.yml
  when: hostvars['localhost'].my_pause.user_input | bool
```

and my output :

```
[root@anisble ansible]# ansible-playbook playbooks/test.yml 



PLAY [dbs] 
********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************
ok: [db1]
ok: [db2]
ok: [db3]

TASK [ssh : pause] ******************************************************************************
[ssh : pause]
Do you want to install mariadb (yes/no)?:
no
  ok: [db1 -> localhost]

TASK [ssh : include_tasks] ***********************************************************************************
included: /etc/ansible/roles/ssh/tasks/mysql.yml for db1, db2, db3

TASK [ssh : install mariadb] ******************************************************************************
ok: [db3]
ok: [db2]
ok: [db1]

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
db1                        : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
db2                        : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
db3                        : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use either a [variable prompt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_prompts.html) or [`pause` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) with `user_input`; and set up a condition for the task:

```
- hosts: my_host_group

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "install_mariadb"
      prompt: "Do you want to install MariaDB (yes/no)?"
      private: no

  tasks:
    - name: install MariaDB
      yum:
        name: MariaDB
        state: present
      when: install_mariadb | bool

    - include_tasks: MySQL.yml
      when: install_mariadb | bool
```

or

```
- hosts: my_host_group

  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "Do you want to install MariaDB (yes/no)?"
      register: my_pause
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: install MariaDB
      yum:
        name: MariaDB
        state: present
      when: hostvars['localhost'].my_pause.user_input | bool

    - include_tasks: MySQL.yml
      when: hostvars['localhost'].my_pause.user_input | bool
```

Comment: another question @techraf. I use second your solution and work only for the first `node` from `hosts`. I have three servers in the hosts group and `MySQL.yml` executed for other servers.(`The second and third nodes`)

Comment: Looks perfectly ok. The file was included, the tasks were `ok`.

Comment: @techraf Second example gives  `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Invalid options for pause: delegate_to,register"}` error. any thoughts ?

Comment: @Juned most probably you have formatted your file wrong and gave delegate_to: and register: the same indent as to prompt: .

Comment: is `mypause`.user_input and `my_pause` typo or is this correct? Looks like it should be `.my_pause.user_input` I didn't test this code. Just reading some things about ansible trying to understand some behaviors :D

Comment: Could add `run_once: true` and `gather_facts: false` and drop the `delegate_to` and `hostvars['localhost'].`.

Comment: @Dwza looks very much like a typo. I've updated the answer now.